# Using the built binary of a docker image in another docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

## Problem

I have two repositories A and B. I have a docker image registry, where I can push the docker images made of the repositories A and B.

I need only the binary of A's source code to be included in the docker image of B. So when running the docker image of B, the jar file of A is present and can be used. And in case of updates in repository A, the registry image is subsequently updated.

## Question

I've searched now several threads and the docker documentation. Is there a recommended way to make this happen with docker respectivly dockerfile commands?

So far I tried the following and it worked, but it wasn't so intiutive. Is this the recommended way?

```
FROM myregistry/my-A-img AS A
FROM ubuntu-base-img

# Build commands for B ...
COPY build-B.jar /app

# Get the A image from the registry
COPY --from=A /path/to/build-A.jar /app/lib

# Run B binaries
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to use the build pattern or the multistage features of docker

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

With that, you can use as many images as you need depending on your build process

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will go with [an external image as stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage) `COPY --from=A:latest path/to/image/jarfile destination`. Then omitting the FROM * AS statement.